# Android SH Shell Scripting

Tags: android, bash, terminal

I try to run an sh script on an android device. The code i use is:

```
am force-stop com.firenav.dsoft.firenav
pm install -r /internal_Storage/download/firenav_dev.apk
am start -n com.firenav.dsoft.firenav/.SplashScreen
```

When I run those commands manually they run fine.
When I put them in an .sh file I get errors.

```
: not found[1]: !#/system/bin/sh
        pkg: /internal_Storage/download/firenav_dev.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
 }arting: Intent { cmp=com.firenav.dsoft.firenav/.SplashScreen
Error type 3
} does not exist.lass {com.firenav.dsoft.firenav/com.firenav.dsoft.firenav.SplashScreen
```

What am I missing here? I'm logged in via adb

Comment: Look at the first line of error "not found": shouldn't it be `#!/system...` instead of `!#/system...`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code you showed as a script on the android device the problem is that you have to copy the file `/internal_Storage/download/firenav_dev.apk` to the device before invoking `pm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Check path permission, path must be set to  rwxrwxr-x and apk must be set to rwxrwxr--

```
 chmod 775 /internal_Storage/download
 chmod 774 /internal_Storage/download/apkfile.apk
```